# date_trunc for two or three months

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm using AWS redshift and I want to date_trunc for every two months,like

`date_trunc('month',summary_date)`

but ideally I would want `date_trunc('2 month',summary_date)`

is it possible to date_trunc every two months or three months?